# Who was the youngest winner of Gagarin Cup?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, records

[Gagarin Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagarin_Cup) is the name for [KHL playoffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontinental_Hockey_League). (KHL is widely considered the second best ice hockey league in the world, after NHL.) In the [last season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Gagarin_Cup_playoffs), 20-years old [Ilya Sorokin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilya_Sorokin) and 19 years old [Ilya Samsonov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilya_Samsonov) played in the final. This is relatively young age for a goaltender. This made me wonder:

- Who was the youngest winner of Gagarin Cup?
- Who was the youngest goaltender, defenseman, forward to win this trophy?

(This is probably clear from the context, but I mean age at the time of winning the cup.)

Answer (score 2):

I am posting a CW answer, feel free to edit it if there are younger Gagarin cup winners that I was able to find. (Or if you can find further references.)

I have searched among players listed as [Gagarin Cup Champions](http://www.eliteprospects.com/awards.php?award=KHL%20Gagarin%20Cup%20Champion) at Elite Prospects.

- **Forwards:** [Kirill Petrov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirill_Petrov) won [2009 Gagarin Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Gagarin_Cup_Finals) at the age of [18 years, 11 months, 30 days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=years+between+april+13+1990+and+april+12+2009) (one day before his 19th birthday).
- **Defencemen:** [Andrei Mironov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrei_Mironov_(ice_hockey)) won [2013 Gagarin Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Gagarin_Cup_playoffs) at the age of [18 years, 8 months, 19 days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=years+between+july+29+1994+and+april+17+2013).
- **Goaltenders:** [Ilya Samsonov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilya_Samsonov) won [2016 Gagarin Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Gagarin_Cup_playoffs) at the age of [19 years, 1 months, 28 days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=years+between+ferbruary+22+1997+and+april+19+2016).